# How to rotate a coordinate system to find the unstable manifold.

Tags: manifolds, dynamical-systems, coordinate-systems, transformation, stability-theory

I am considering the dynamical system:
$u'=v-0.25(v-u)^2$
$v'=u(1+v)+0.25(u+v)^2$

I have calculated the linear stable and unstable manifold as, 
$E^s=sp(1,1)$ and $E^u=sp(-1,1)$ for eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$ respectively. I did this by calculating the linear eigenvalues and vectors and then using the defintions for the linear stable and unstable manifolds:

$E^s$
is the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalues with negative real parts. Let $v_1, . . . , v_k ⊂ R^n$
be the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues of $D(\bar{x})f$ having negative real parts.
$E^s = sp{v_1, . . . , v_k}$.

$E^u$ is equivalent for a positive eigenvalue.

I am now trying to calculate an approximation for the unstable manifold but believe I should transform my system so that the linear unstable manifold is of the form ${(x,0):x\in\Re} but I am unsure on how to this.

My initial idea was to let $y=\tilde{y}-1$ but that doesn't satisfy the above for all y, which is where I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
u'&=v-\frac14(v-u)^2\\
v'&=u(1+v)+\frac14(u+v)^2
\end{align}
With the transformation $U=u+v$, $V=u-v$ (there is no real need to use rotations, the scaling here doesn't hurt), you get
\begin{align}
U'&=U-\frac12V^2+\frac12U^2\\
V'&=-V-\frac12U^2\\
\end{align}
The unstable manifold $\mathcal{U}$ is, to linear approximation, $V=0$.
So to obtain better approximations, we can impose an ansatz
$$
V=a_2U^2+a_3U^3+a_4U^4+\dots
$$
and see what invariance gives us.  Differentiating, we get $V'=(2a_2U+3a_3U^2+4a_4U^3+\dots)U'$.  Substituting for $U',V'$ from the differential equation (by invariance), we have
$$
-V-\frac12U^2 =(2a_2U+3a_3U^2+4a_4U^3+\dots)(U-\frac12V^2+\frac12U^2)
$$
and substituting our ansatz $V=a_2U^2+a_3U^3+a_4U^4+\dots$,
\begin{multline}
-(a_2U^2+a_3U^3+a_4U^4+\dots)-\frac12U^2 =(2a_2U+3a_3U^2+4a_4U^3+\dots)\times\\\left(U-\frac12(a_2U^2+a_3U^3+a_4U^4+\dots)^2+\frac12U^2\right)
\end{multline}
Equating coefficients,
\begin{align}
-a_2-\frac12&=2a_2&a_2&=-\frac16\\
-a_3&=a_2+3a_3 & a_3&=\frac1{24}\\
-a_4&=\frac32a_3+4a_4 & a_4&=-\frac1{80}\\&&\vdots
\end{align}
Finally, you might want to transform back to the original $u,v$ coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I think I follow what you have done but why do you choose the transformation you do?

Comment: Shouldn't for the coeff $U^3: \ -a_3=a_2^2+3a_3+a_2$?

Comment: Where does the $a_2^2$ come from?